# Sort list based on priority from a map

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a simple map and need to create a list that is sorted based on the number in ascending order from a given list:

```
Map auto = new HashMap();
auto.put("Merc", 3);
auto.put("Citroen", 5);
auto.put("Opel", 10);
auto.put("BMW", 20);

List<String> given = new ArrayList<>();
given.add("Opel");
given.add("BMW");
given.add("Citroen");
```

So the given list needs to be sorted so that it will be in this order: Citroen, Opel, BMW. Was thinking of:

1. create another map then iterate through list
2. get number from first map
3. put the number as the key and the name as value in the new map
4. sort the map by key
5. iterate threw new map then add values to the list

This seems terrible :/, any suggestions and perhaps better data structures to use?

Comment: What happens to `Merc`?

Comment: @mercury And why does Citrogen come after BMW,unless i lost counting :P :)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: It looks like the OP wants to sort the members of the *list* based on their values in the map, *not* the keys of the map as a whole.  It looks like your answer below misses that, too.

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java

Comment: @PeterLawrey in this case merc is not used. So if the map has 20 values and the list has 6 values it only needs to sort the 6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Java 8 you can do.

```
Map<String, Integer> auto = new HashMap<>();
auto.put("Merc", 3);
auto.put("Citroen", 5);
auto.put("Opel", 10);
auto.put("BMW", 20);

List<String> given = new ArrayList<>();
given.add("Opel");
given.add("BMW");
given.add("Citroen");

// to sort the selected elements.
given.sort(Comparator.comparing(auto::get));

// to sort all elements.
List<String> names = auto.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Breaking this down

```
List<String> names = 
         // give the set of entries as a Stream.
         auto.entrySet().stream()
        // sort these entries, using the field returned by getValue()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
        // now sorted, turn each Entry into just the getKey()
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        // now we have a stream of keys, turn this into a List<String>
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Can you explain a little?\

Answer (score 5):

[`Collections#sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator))

```
Collections.sort(given, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return auto.get(o1).compareTo(auto.get(o2));
    }
});
```

Or with lambda:

```
Collections.sort(given, (o1, o2) -> auto.get(o1).compareTo(auto.get(o2)));
```

---

Java 8 null-safe solution *inspired from multiple answers*

```
given.sort(Comparator.comparing((s) -> auto.getOrDefault(s, Integer.MAX_VALUE)));
```

Comment: For the lamdba example, I would do `auto.getOrDefault(o1, Integer.MAX_VALUE)` in case of unmapped values.

Answer (score 3):

With Java 8, you could just do

```
given.sort(Comparator.comparing(auto::get));
```

...and it's just that one-liner.  Or with the Guava library you could do

```
Collections.sort(given, Ordering.natural().onResultOf(Functions.forMap(auto)));
```

Comment: can you explain little?

Comment: To explain, [Comparator.comparing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) creates a Comparator implementation that applies the given function to each element and compares the results. In this case, `auto::get` will take a string from the list and return the number it's mapped to in `auto`, so the list will be sorted by these corresponding numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Car` class that implements `Comparable` and includes the name and priority.

Then you can sort lists with `Collections.sort()` directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String,Integer> auto = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
auto.put("Merc", 3);
auto.put("Citroen", 5);
auto.put("Opel", 10);
auto.put("BMW", 20);

Set<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> set = auto.entrySet();
List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>(set);
Collections.sort(list,new Comparator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>(){

             @Override
            public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> o1,
                    Entry<String, Integer> o2) {

                return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
            }
});
```

**Once you have List Objects of Map.Entry,you can extract key using `Entry.getKey()`**

Comment: Entry doesn't have a `compareTo` method.

Comment: It implies that `given` is a map, but the question state that both are distinct (eg: a map and list). Also, while the question does not state it, the map may not have duplicate values while the list may.